# how to select single value in vuetify table

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a vuetify table where I can select values which are pushed later on to an array. My problem is that I have to give a key to the table in order to be able to select/push to array. But this key causes the problem of selecting multiple rows. But I want each to be a single select row. Could someone help me out with that? I am kinda stuck on how to fix this error: I just copied my table as the problem is there:

```
<v-col>
      <v-data-table
        v-model="selected"
        :headers="headers"
        :items="meetingTimes"
        item-key="date"
        show-select
        class="elevation-1"
      >

      </v-data-table>
```

axios method:

```
 getMeetingTimes() {
      var pageURL = window.location.href;
      var lastURLSegment = pageURL.substr(pageURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
      axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/meetingTime/findBy", {

        params: {
          meetingName: lastURLSegment,
        }

      })
        .then(response => (this.meetingTimes = response.data))

    },
```

Answer (score 1):

That indicates multiple items have the same value of `item-key`, where the items with the same `item-key` are shown as selected in the table ([demo 1](https://codesandbox.io/s/duplicate-item-key-in-v-data-table-by3x4?file=/src/components/MyTable.vue)).

The `item-key` must be unique to avoid the problem. You could add an `id` property to each item in the array, and remove the `item-key="date"` attribute from the template because `"id"` is the default for `item-key`.

You could [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the API response's array into a new array, with an `id`
property added:

```js
let nextId = 0

export default {
  methods: {
    getMeetingTimes() {
      axios.get('/api/data').then(response => {
        // map `resp.data[]` to new array items, adding `id` property
        this.meetingTimes = response.data.map(time => ({
          id: nextId++,
          ...time
        }))
      })
    },
  },
}
```

Since you're sending the selected meeting times to a backend that doesn't allow the extra `id` property, you can remove the property before sending it, again through a mapping:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    sendSelectedTimes() {
      // map `selected[]` to new array, without `id` property
      const selectedTimes = this.selected?.map(time => {
        const { id, ...otherProps } = time
        return otherProps
      })

      console.log({ selectedTimes })
    }
  }
}
```

[demo 2](https://codesandbox.io/s/selecting-items-in-v-data-table-forked-ob7sx?file=/src/components/MyTable.vue)

Comment: I will try it tommorow and tell you then :) I will upvote your comments so your efforts are not in vain today thanks again

Comment: @haso Updated answer with a solution that I think better suits your use case